# Как избавиться от повторение кода php

Tags: php

Как избавиться от повторения кода?

```
if(!empty($yml_category[strval($row->categoryId)])){
            $offer_category = $yml_category[strval($row->categoryId)]['name']." | ";
            $parentId = $yml_category[strval($row->categoryId)]['parentId'];

            if($parentId !== 0){
                $offer_category = $offer_category.$yml_category[$parentId]['name']." | ";
                $parentId = $yml_category[$parentId]['parentId'];

                if($parentId !== 0){
                    $offer_category = $offer_category.$yml_category[$parentId]['name']." | ";
                    $parentId = $yml_category[$parentId]['parentId'];

                    if($parentId !== 0){
                        $offer_category = $offer_category.$yml_category[$parentId]['name']." | ";
                        $parentId = $yml_category[$parentId]['parentId'];

                        if($parentId !== 0){
                            $offer_category = $offer_category.$yml_category[$parentId]['name']." | ";
                            $parentId = $yml_category[$parentId]['parentId'];

                            if($parentId !== 0){
                                $offer_category = $offer_category.$yml_category[$parentId]['name']." | ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: не писать повторы. пример входных данных, и что вы хотите сделать напишите. а то глаза вытекут пока чиатешь

Comment: Сделать на рекурсии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$offer_category = '';
do {
  $offer_category .= $yml_category[strval($row->categoryId)]['name']." | ";
  $parentId = $yml_category[strval($row->categoryId)]['parentId'];
while ($parentId !== 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как обычно - использовать циклы

```php
$category = strval($row->categoryId);
if(!empty($yml_category[$category])) {
  $offer_category = "";
  do {
    $offer_category .= $yml_category[$category]['name'] . " | ";
    $category = $yml_category[$category]['parentId'];
  } while ($category !== 0);
}
```

Comment: А как выйти из цикла? parentId ни где не присваивается

Comment: И цикл не закрыт

Comment: @Walfter так лучше?

Comment: Почти=))) Наверное ещё надо `$offer_category .= $yml***`=)))

Comment: @Walfter уже заметил :)